# Postgresql: Modal share aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, statistics, aggregate-functions

I need to calculate the number of values that are equal to the aggregate mode
so for values 6,7,7,7,8 mode is 7 and modal_count is 3, modal_share is 3/5

I need a modal count or a modal share as an aggregate function.

I tried modifying the mode function to give the modal count, but I am getting an error about int being too small

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_mode_count(anyarray)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM unnest($1) a
    GROUP BY a
    ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, a
    LIMIT 1;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;

-- Tell Postgres how to use our aggregate
CREATE AGGREGATE mode_count(anyelement) (
  SFUNC=array_append, --Function to call for each row. Just builds the array
  STYPE=anyarray,
  FINALFUNC=_final_mode_count, --Function to call after everything has been added to array
  INITCOND='{}' --Initialize an empty array when starting
);
```

Runs fine, but when I call it I get

```
FEHLER:  Rückgabetyp von Funktion stimmt nicht überein; deklariert als integer
DETAIL:  Eigentlicher Rückgabetyp ist bigint.
CONTEXT:  SQL-Funktion „_final_mode_share“ beim Start
********** Error **********

FEHLER: Rückgabetyp von Funktion stimmt nicht überein; deklariert als integer
SQL state: 42P13
Detail: Eigentlicher Rückgabetyp ist bigint.
Context: SQL-Funktion „_final_mode_share“ beim Start
```

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count(*) returns a bigint, which is what the type of your final function's return should be (instead of "RETURNS anyelement AS" use "RETURNS bigint AS").

Comment: thank you! welcome to stack, glad to see there's more postgres users coming in :)

Comment: Thanks! Long time lurker, finally taking some time to participate :)